# what is the best way to implement one-time login feature

Tags: android, ios, android-sharedpreferences

**I would like my app has the following feature:**

User login with username and passowrd when first time install the app on phone. After successfully logged in, everytime when user launch the app again, the app doesn't ask for login credential again, but directly shows the landing screen. (Of course if user clear app data, the app will ask for login again)

**The way to implement the feature in my mind could be** that the app stores  username and password in `SharedPreferences` once user login successfully, then, when user launch the app again, my code could check if there are username and password in `ShareadPrefereces`, if so, directly show the landing page.

**My question:**

I am not sure whether it is safe or really a good practice to store user's login credential in `SharedPreferences`? If not, what is the best way to implement this one-time login feature?

(I am doing it for both Android and iOS. So, I would like to hear both Android good solution and iOS solution. Thanks!)

Comment: AccountManager is the Android way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice to store credentials in `SharedPreferences`. In fact it's bad to store credentials anywhere on user's device.

Using some encrypting library, for example [Hawk](https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk) for android would be a better, but still not recommended option.

Better way would require some work on the backend side: in return to user's credentials server would return a token which can be used leter for authorization. The token would expire in some fixed amount of time (like day, week, etc.). Before this time passes you can make another request and update your token for a new one which will live another week (day, month etc.)

Even better approach would be to save the token using Hawk (or some other similar lib)